# Why can I only propose migration to meta?

Tags: support, flagging, migration

I saw a question that really belonged on another stack exchange site, but when I tried to flag it as needing migration, the only option I had was to select migration to meta. So, I didn't flag it.

Why was meta the only option on the migration list?

Comment: I'm not sure why the linked duplicate is also a duplicate, but there are a couple of questions. Basically, migration to a site other than meta is mod-only.